# External css stylesheet not working without thymeleaf

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I'm trying to figure out a reason why i have to include thymeleaf in my html tag and in my link to my external css stylesheet in the head. If i remove any of it, the stylesheet will be disconnected from the html document. So why are the thymeleaf bits necessary to include?
the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{style.css}" href="..\css\style.css">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Nice -->
<div id="header" class="header"></div>
<div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <a href="filmInfo.html"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.nfbio.dk/sites/nfbio.dk/files/styles/movie_poster/public/movie-posters/HO00002857_104360.jpg?itok=pRMFGS5R" alt="..."></a></div>
        <div class="col">
            <a href="filmInfo2.html"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.nfbio.dk/sites/nfbio.dk/files/styles/movie_poster/public/media-images/2022-09/Amsterdam_Payoff_Poster_68%2C5x101%2C5_DK_72dpi_0.jpg?itok=yX9_nT_-" alt="..."></a>
            Titel her</div>
        <div class="col">
            <a href="filmInfo3.html"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.nfbio.dk/sites/nfbio.dk/files/styles/movie_poster/public/movie-posters/HO00002845_104348.jpg?itok=jNJskf23" alt="..."></a>
            Titel her</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://videnskab.dk/files/article_media/gnaver.png" alt="...">
            Titel her </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://videnskab.dk/files/article_media/gnaver.png" alt="...">
            Titel her</div>
        <div class="col">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://videnskab.dk/files/article_media/gnaver.png" alt="...">
            Titel her</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://videnskab.dk/files/article_media/gnaver.png" alt="...">
            Titel her </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://videnskab.dk/files/article_media/gnaver.png" alt="...">
            Titel her</div>
        <div class="col">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://videnskab.dk/files/article_media/gnaver.png" alt="...">
            Titel her</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    $(function(){
        $('#header').load('reuse-header.html');
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see backslashes in your href: `href="..\css\style.css"`. Did you mean forward slashes (`/`)? Where is that stylesheet in relation to the HTML template? What does the browser network monitor say  about its failure to locate the CSS file? (F12 to open)

Comment: You mentioned that `thymeleaf` needs to be added in the CSS links but the example code above doesn't share that. Can you share how you're adding it in the CSS link? is it in the path or through an attribute of the link tag?

Comment: Can you share how and where are you using this HTML doc? Is it a part of a spring project that loads/configures it as a template for rendering pages?

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan - "_the example code above doesn't share that_" What about `th:href="@{style.css}"`? I assume that is what the question is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Well the namespace attribute defines the tags we can use or more specifically where to find the definition for tags for the framework that will compile this document for it to be readable by the browser.

You have provided the `https://www.thymeleaf.org`(name it thyme leaf,  not sure what it is called) library as the source of where it can find definitions for and uses of tags in this document.

What this implies is that, now the thyme library provides definitions for tags. Meaning a simple `img` tag like  this:

```
<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
```

could be coded(subject to thymes provided interface/tags for developing a document) like this:

```
<ThymeImg Thyme:customWayForSrc="img_girl.jpg" FormatwithColonIsThymeChoiceAlt="Girl in a jacket" thyme:width="500" th:height="600">
```

I believe they used or allowed to set the `src` attribute in a similar convention to the standard dialect of HTML by just pre-pending a thyme prefix to `src` attribute so that developers don't get lost by a total new convention. They could have named it anything e.g `setSRC`. You should read their [docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html) to get acquainted with their dialect of developing documents.

why create a new dialect? Usually, it's for the purpose of efficiency. You can read their philosophy behind creating a new dialect for HTML [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#introducing-thymeleaf:%7E:text=template%20by%20Thymeleaf.-,1.3,-Dialects%3A%20The%20Standard) on their landing page.

Comment: The inclusion of the namespace `xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"` is an _incantation_ for Thymeleaf. That is to say, it's there for no other reason than to prevent the IDE from complaining about unknown use of `th:`. It "_has no influence at all in template processing_". ([Reference](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#a-multi-language-welcome)). I am not sure that the rest of the answer is relevant to the question - but please correct me if I have missed the point.

Comment: I'm not sure about this particular case. The tag `<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">`  does not have any implication to how the template is processed

Comment: but Thyme's Engine does require the convention to able to compile a document, which will finally be an HTML5  depending on what is the desired out file is. The engine [configuration]( https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#a-multi-language-welcome:~:text=engine%20is%20initialized.-,2.2%20Creating%20and%20configuring%20the%20Template%20Engine,-The%20process(%E2%80%A6) ) in the example talks about configuring the engine to create a web page but the documents share the range of documents it can be compiled to.

Comment: The rest of the answers explains why the `th` is used because it's part of  Thyme's dialect and is used by Thyme Engine to be able to process it and  develop a document depending how it's configured in the project, doesn't necessarily have to be a webpage

Answer (score 0):

Use this then your external css works

Comment: Suggestion: Take a look at the Stack Overflow [markdown formatting guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Your HTML is hidden, currently.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).